# Need to make changes to MS Project 2003 files (MPP) from .Net - what are my options?

Tags: .net, ms-project

I have the need to make changes to MS Project files from a .Net program.

My company has Apose.Task but I've just realized today that it apparently only allows for reading MPP files, writing is supported for XML only. Can anyone say I'm wrong about Apose?!!!

Is there other products or open source alternatives?

Can we use COM to do this, and if this is a way (even if it requires some additional work), does anyone have examples/references?

We have the structure in place in an existing file but needs to manipulate start time, end time, progress etc. for some of the tasks.

Any input appreciated!

Comment: What kind of program do you need to access it from? Winforms? WebForms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use COM, if you press Alt-F11 inside MS-Project, it will open the VBA editor, from there you can get to the help file to see full Object Model documentation.